# Open all for Accordion / print all

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, accordion

I have put together a page with accordion function so the page is not too long, now when I want to print the page it will only print the section which is opened, I would love to have a open all button or print all button implemented, any help is greatly appreciated!

Could someone please help?

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #13294b;
  border: 2px solid #59cbe8;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #cccccc;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  margin: 4px 0px 7px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #1f447b;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #59cbe8;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Title 1</button>
<div class="panel">content</div>

<button class="accordion">Title 2</button>
<div class="panel">content</div>
```

Comment: Just add a "Print" button that, when clicked, loops through the panels and sets each one's `height` to the "open" height and invoke the `window.print()` method. Then, trigger the `click` event of the active panel to reset all the heights.

Comment: hi Scott, thanks for the information, bit new to the javascript, are you able to direct me through this? cheers

Comment: hello, please help

Answer (score 0):

just use media query print https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries.

for example:

```css
.accordion .collapsed {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media print {
    .accordion .collapsed {
         height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="accordion">
    <li class="collapsed">this is hidden</li>
    <li class="collapsed">this is hidden</li>
    <li>this is not hidden</li>
    <li class="collapsed">this is hidden</li>
    <li class="collapsed">this is hidden</li>
    <li class="collapsed">this is hidden</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

Comment: thanks, your code is perfect, could you please show me how to apply this on to my existing CSS code? current code is applied crossed section, don't really want to redo everything, thanks

Comment: 1st, you need to find the css that hides the accordion elements, which in mine is `.accordion .collapse`, then you just need to override it with media query print, in my code, i hide it with `height:0` and override it with `height: auto`, other method is hide it with `display: none` and override it with `display: block`, it depends on your code, if you can't fine it, you can update your css in the question to include the accordion parts, so that I or someone can spot it for you